# Can you please give me time approximation(like n^2 , n*2 , nlogn) of this New Selection Sort Algorithm made by me

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

New Modified Selection Sort Algorithm (It outperforms Insertion Sort in some cases) goes like standard Selection Sort Algorithm , but instead searching for only a minimum in an Array , it searches for minimum and maximum in one iteration. Then it swaps minimum to start of an Array and maximum to end of an Array. Increments `start_pointer`, decrements `end_pointer`, and then goes iterative again. I think time complexity it needs to sort N size array is : `N + (N-2) + (N-4) + (N-6) + ... + 1`. Can someone give me approximation of this formula. I will be appreciated.

```
public static void DoubleSelectionSort(int[] Array, int startpos, int endpos) {

    /*Double Selection Sort Algorithm , made by Milan Domonji 1986 , MilanDomonji@yahoo.com*/

    while(startpos < endpos) {

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int minpos = startpos;
        int maxpos = endpos;

        for(int i = startpos; i <= endpos; i++) {
            //main loop that finds minimum and maximum from an Array

            if (Array[i] <= min) {
                min = Array[i];
                minpos = i;
            }

            if (Array[i] >= max) {
                max = Array[i];
                maxpos = i;
            }   

        }
        /* I added missing part of algorithm so it works now (Edited) */
        if (maxpos==startpos && minpos==endpos) {

            Swap(Array, minpos, maxpos);

        }else {
             if (maxpos==startpos) {

                Swap(Array,minpos,startpos);
                Swap(Array,minpos,endpos);              

             }else {

               Swap(Array,minpos,startpos);
               Swap(Array,maxpos,endpos);

          }
        }

        startpos++;
        endpos--;
  }
}

private static void Swap(int[] Array, int A, int B) {

    int tmp = Array[A];
    Array[A] = Array[B];
    Array[B] = tmp;

}
```

Algorithm Sorts all the times correctly.

Comment: What about simply profiling the algorithm with different values of n and compare the results with n², 2*n, nlogn ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need sum `S = N + (N-2) + (N-4) + ... + (N - (N-2))` (For example `N` is even), it is equal to `S = 2 + 4 + ... + N = 2 ( 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N/2) = 2 * N/2 * (N/2 + 1)/2 = N/2 * (N/2 +1) =  Theta(N^2)`

Comment: Meh , Algorithm does performs better then Selection sort by 50%.This Algorithm outperforms Insertion Sort in first run.Repeatedly performing Insertion Sort it drops it's run time by 50 %.(eg first run 2.1 seconds , after couple of runs 1.05 seconds). I guess this is cause of memory allocation and the way Java moves memory in array.(No I didn't made mistake of sorting already sorted array using Insertion Sort.) (All Tests are done on 100.000 Integers.)